# Asp.net how can I send a list from codebehind to javascript for displaying coordinates in googlemap

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, google-maps

I am currently new in working with asp.net. I wish to use googlemap to display a list of gps locations on a map.

I have this button event that calls a webservice in my backend, it returns a list of coordinates(latitude/longitude). And this works fine. My question is how I can send this list to javascript in my aspx page.

```
protected void btnGetMapForAdr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<MultipleAddress> listofaddr;
            MultipleAddress multiAddr1;
            MultipleAddress multiAddr2;
            MultipleAddress multiAddr3;
            ...

            listofaddr = new List<MultipleAddress>()
            {
                multiAddr1,
                multiAddr2,
                multiAddr3
            };


            //Class1 is a library that contains the webservice method that returns the coordinates.

            Class1 service = new Class1();
            Dictionary<string, LongitudeLatitude> returnAdrListDict = service.GetMultipleLongLat(listofaddr);

            List<LongitudeLatitude> newListForASPX = CreateNewList(returnAdrListDict);

            List<string> listForJavascript = ConvertToListOfStrings(newListForASPX);

        }
        //convert dictionary to type LongitudeLatitude
            private List<LongitudeLatitude> CreateNewList(Dictionary<string, LongitudeLatitude> input){
            List<LongitudeLatitude> longlatListCollection = new List<LongitudeLatitude>();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, LongitudeLatitude> item in input)
            {
                LongitudeLatitude adrlonglat = new LongitudeLatitude();
                adrlonglat.AdressInfo = item.Key;
                adrlonglat.Latitude = item.Value.Latitude;
                adrlonglat.Longitude = item.Value.Longitude;

                longlatListCollection.Add(adrlonglat);

            }
                 return longlatListCollection;
            }

        //convert list of type LongitudeLatitude to a list of type string
           private List<string> ConvertToListOfStrings(List<LongitudeLatitude> input)
           {
               List<string> listToReturn = new List<string>(); 
               foreach (var item in input)
               {
                   listToReturn.Add(item.AdressInfo.ToString() + ":" + item.Latitude.ToString() + "," + item.Longitude.ToString());
               }
               return listToReturn;
           }
        }
```

I found this example of how to show multiple locations with markers in googlemap but i do not know how to send the list (listToReturn) from code behind to javascript in aspx page. I have tried to use the following hiddenfield, autopostback, session but nothing seems to work, maybe there is something I am doing wrong.

```
<%--<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      var locations = [
        ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
        ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
        ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
        ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
        ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
      ];

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 10,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      var marker, i;

      for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
              map: map
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
              return function () {
                  infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
              }
          })(marker, i));
      }
  </script>
</body>
</html>--%>
```

Comment: Can I kindly get more ideas on how I can solve this tasks. I am new to asp.net and have not much experience with front end(javascript...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a little alien to googlemaps as I have never worked on it, but if you want to return a list from code to javascript on button click then how about making a `jquery ajax` call and returning the list in the form of `json`? You can use this list in the `success` part of the `ajax` call.

There is a good example here.

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/96/Handling-JSON-Arrays-returned-from-ASP.NET-Web-Services-with-jQuery

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have no clue about jquery/ajax. it is probably something i have to look at later

Comment: Then i think it is high time you starting knowing it because it makes life much simpler as far as javascript is concerned. Rest is your call. :)

Answer (score 0):

I use an extension method:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Registers an object as a variable on the page
        /// </summary>
        public static void RegisterObjectAsVariable(this ClientScriptManager mgr, Type type, string variableName, object objectToEncode)
        {
            mgr.RegisterClientScriptBlock(type,
                string.Concat("ClientScriptManagerExtensions_", variableName),
                string.Concat("var ", variableName, " = ", new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(objectToEncode), ";"),
                true);
        }
```

This is very easy to call from code, you can even use an anonymous type:

```
var locations = new[]
{
  new {latitude = 1, longitude = 1},
  new {latitude = 2, longitude = 2},
  new {latitude = 3, longitude = 3},
};

this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterObjectAsVariable(typeof(MyPage), "locations", locations);
```

This will create a javascript object called locations on the page for you to access.

Comment: But the object i have to register, is it the returned list from my method call? this list contains a list of strings ´code´       public static void RegisterObjectAsVariable(this ClientScriptManager mgr, Type type, string listToReturn, object objectToEncode)
        {
            mgr.RegisterClientScriptBlock(type,
                string.Concat("ClientScriptManagerExtensions_", variableName),
                string.Concat("var ", listToReturn, " = ", new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(objectToEncode), ";"),
                true);
        }

Comment: @user3058620 the object is whatever you want to put in your JS variable. I've suggested latitude/longitude, you can then loop over these in JS and create the google.maps.LatLng() objects